# Collision detection - formula for getting intersection point

Tags: collision-detection, intersection

I need help with collision detection algorithm from this paper: http://www.peroxide.dk/papers/collision/collision.pdf

I assume I am colliding with sphere of radius 1, just to make everything not important easier...I am concerned with formula, which finds intersection point with plane (page 14):

planeIntersectionPoint = basePoint - planeNormal + t0 * velocity

where:
basePoint = center of Sphere

planeNormal = normalized normal vector to colliding plane

t0 = number from [0,1] interval, first moment from this interval during which collision happens, assuming we are moving with velocity vector

velocity = velocity vector

I think that this formula doesn't work... Assuming that I am already intersecting with plane at t0 = 0, I just get:

planeIntersectionPoint = basePoint - planeNormal

What gives me point which doesn't even belong to plane, what fails further parts of the algorithm, when I check if intersection point is in triangle...

I will be grateful for every answer... Is the algorithm wrong, or that's me misunderstanding something?...

Comment: Check this answer: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/171994/95868

Comment: Thanks for comment! I use that formula later, but the problem is with case when I am colliding with a plane when t0 = 0... Then my calculated intersection point isn't lying on colliding plane and rest of the algorithm is fucked up...

Comment: If you are **just touching** the plane, without penetration, your formula gives ``planeIntersectionPoint = basePoint - planeNormal * radius`` (I included the radius for completeness). The formula is correct. However, if the sphere is **penetrating** the plane, you have two intersection points. Which case describes your situation?

Comment: My case is sphere penetrating the plane. In this case this formula returns point, which doesn't belong to the plane. And in paper it is still used, this case isn't treated differently... Sorry for not being clear enough :(

Comment: Is it 3D or 2D ? In 2D you get two intersection points. In 3D you get a whole circle. Why do you need these points? If it's for collision response, you dont need to use them, you can just update the velocity vector.

Comment: It is 3D. Finding this point is part of collision detection algorithm. (btw algorithm works well, it starts to fail when I add response and I am looking for flaws) In order to detect a collision, I need to find an intersection point. Then I check if point is inside a triangle. But ofc procedure checking if point is inside triangle needs to have point, which is lying on the same plane as triangle is, otherwise it can return wrong result...